# How can I create a bbappend file to force the Git Fetcher to download a specific version of a software from GitHub?

Tags: git, github, yocto, yocto-recipe, hiredis

I'm using the `zeus` Yocto release as Linux build system. In this release the recipe for `hiredis` ([hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) is a minimalistic C client library for the Redis database) fetches and compiles the version `0.14.0` of this library.

I would like to use a more recent version of this library; in particular my goal is to fetch and compile the version `1.0.2` of `hiredis`.

#### The hiredis recipe in the `zeus` release of Yocto

The recipe `hiredis_0.14.0.bb`, stored in the folder `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-extended/hiredis` of the `zeus` release, is the following:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Minimalistic C client library for Redis"
HOMEPAGE = "http://github.com/redis/hiredis"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
SECTION = "libs"
DEPENDS = "redis"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d84d659a35c666d23233e54503aaea51"
SRCREV = "685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=git \
           file://0001-Makefile-remove-hardcoding-of-CC.patch"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools-brokensep pkgconfig

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "PREFIX=${prefix} LIBRARY_PATH=${baselib}"

# By default INSTALL variable in Makefile is equal to 'cp -a', which preserves
# ownership and causes host-user-contamination QA issue.
# And PREFIX defaults to /usr/local.
do_install_prepend() {
  export INSTALL='cp -r'
}
```

With this recipe `bitbake` fetches the version `0.14.0` of `hiredis` from the GitHub repository. I suppose that the version `0.14.0` is selected by the version of the recipe contained in its name "hiredis_**0.14.0**".

**Note**: I don't want to modify the recipe `hiredis_0.14.0.bb` or add a new recipe (with the name `hiredis_1.0.2.bb`) in the folder `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-extended/hiredis`. I would like to create a `.bbappend` file in my meta layer without modify the official `meta-openembedded` layer of the `zeus` release.

#### Set `SRC_URI` not work

I have tried to create a file `hiredis_%.bbappend` with the following definition of the variable `SRC_URI`:

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=git;branch=1.0.2"
```

But the compilation with `bitbake` gives the following error message:

```
> bitbake hiredis
...
ERROR: hiredis-0.14.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=git;branch=1.0.2'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

#### My question

How can I create a `my-layer/recipes-extended/hredis/hredis_%.bbappend` file to force the Git Fetcher to download a specific version of `hredis` (for example the version `1.0.2`) from the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by the creation of the following `hiredis_%.bbappend` file:

```
PV="1.0.2"

# In SRC_URI I have change values of the protocol and the branch parameters
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=https;branch=master"

# Commit Hash of version 1.0.2 of hiredis library
SRCREV = "b731283245f3183af527237166261ad0768ba7d4"

inherit cmake
```

In this way the Git Fetcher downloads the version `1.0.2` from the GitHub repository and in the image is installed the dynamic library `libhiredis.so.1.0.0` (the version showed by the name of the library is `1.0.0` instead `1.0.2`).

#### Description of the file `hiredis_%.bbappend`

- set the variable `PV=1.0.2` (this select the version `1.0.2` instead `0.14.0` set by the recipe name)
- set the Git Fetcher parameters in `SRC_VALUE` as `protocol=https;branch=master` instead `protocol=git;branch=1.0.2` (see the attempt shown in the question)
- set the `SRCREV` equal to *git commit hash* of the version 1.0.2
- add the instruction `inherit cmake` because the version `1.0.2` use CMake